# R - Loop into n columns of x dataframes and plot each variables in the same graph

Tags: r, dataframe, list, loops

I have been looking at other similar posts but cannot figure it out.
I have a large number of dataframes, each having a large number of columns n. It's important to note that each dataframe has the same number of columns with the same name and in the same order.

Let's say

```
df1<-data.frame(col1=c(1979:2150),...., coln=c(1:172))
... # many more dataframes with the same format
dfn<-data.frame(col1=c(1979:2150),...., coln(c(1:172)) 

All_dataframes<-list(df1, df2, df3,...,dfn)
```

I have first been trying to create one single graph for one specific column of each data frame of my list, which seems to work with the following simple code (I could not manage to do that with lapply, happy to take suggestions too)

```
my_plot<-ggplot(bind_rows(All_dataframes, .id = "df"), aes(x=Year, y=col17, colour=df))+
         geom_line()
```

I would now like to create a loop to go through every similar column of each dataframe included in the list to plot those variables in the same graph (same as this example before, but without having to specify the columns, my dataset is too big). For example, having all the col12 of each dataframe to be plotted together, all col13, col14...

Bonus: I would also love to add a geom_smooth for each variable... Not sure how to add that.

I would really appreciate if the answer could include the explanation of what is being done. I want to understand the steps.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make a reproducible example with 2 y columns to plot, and different data so we can tell if it works:

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = runif(20), col3 = runif(20))
df2 <- data.frame(col1=c(2001:2020), col2 = rnorm(20), col3 = rnorm(20)) 

All_dataframes <- list(df1, df2)
one_dataframe = bind_rows(All_dataframes, .id = "df")
```

We can then make a list for the plots, and use a for loop to populate the list, using `.data[[column_name]]` inside `aes()` to specify the changing aesthetics. (The `.data` syntax was introduced in ggplot2 version 3.0, I believe.)

```
## create empty list to put plots in
plot_list = list()

## set which columns we want to use as y values
## as a character vector
y_cols = setdiff(names(one_dataframe), c("df", "col1"))

## loop over the columns and assign the plots to the list
for(col in y_cols) {
  plot_list[[col]] = 
    ggplot(one_dataframe, aes(x = col1, y = .data[[col]], col = df)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth() + 
    labs(title = col)
}
```

Accessing individual plots can be done by number or column name:

```
plot_list[[1]]
```

[image]

```
plot_list[["col3"]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works! Quick questions for my understanding: When you set columns to use as y-values, do you use setdiff to test for unique column names? Also, what is the need to put c("df", "col1") after? Last question: why plot_list[[col]]? Is that not the plots that you assign the plot_list?

Comment: You can construct the vector of column names however you want. You could list them out `y_cols = c("col2", "col3", "my_favorite_column")` you could construct them `y_cols = paste0("col", 2:100)`. What `setdiff(names(one_dataframe), c("df", "col1"))` is "all the column in `one_dataframe` except for `df` and `col1`.

Comment: `plot_list[[col]]` is a names an item of `plot_list` named as current value of `col` - it will create it if it doesn't already exist. Doing it that way is what let's you use the names later, so you can do `plot_list[["col3"]]` and it works.